# Is this load bearing wall?

Tags: framing, load-bearing, load

This is a 10' wall with the roof joists running on top of it. Really doesn't seem like it's supporting much. It's pretty flimsy except the newer cutout for the opening that was installed. Would a strongback be sufficient to keep the roof joists form sagging?

[image]

[image]?

Comment: A picture/s of the wall will help, but walls running that way in/near the centre of a building have a very high chance of being load bearing.  If that wall did have an opening made into it, I would want to see an engineered design for it.

Comment: That wall does not seem to be near the centre of the house.  Is there another wall at the centre or is that it?  If another wall then you should be okay, but that is a good header in the opening.  Is there a basement in that house?  If so there should be a big beam.  The wall right above that beam is your load bearing wall. Most other walls are separation walls.

Comment: That's the only wall. No basement just crawl space.

Answer (score 1):

No.

- The header isn't substantial enough.
- The plates above the header aren't supported well enough.
- Your engineered trusses don't have bearing points over the wall.
- It stops partway through a uniform series of trusses, each of which would presumably need the same support.

You can remove it without consequence. The ceiling joists are designed to span that distance.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm looking through a tiny hole in the internet. Accept my response with due discretion and no liability whatsoever.</sub>